# Can you escape from hold person after failing the inital check?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

**[Hold Person](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/hold-person/)**:

> The subject becomes paralyzed and freezes in place. It is aware and breathes normally but **cannot take any actions**, even speech. Each round on its turn, the subject may attempt a new saving throw to end the effect. **This is a full-round action** that does not provoke attacks of opportunity. A winged creature who is paralyzed cannot flap its wings and falls. A swimmer can’t swim and may drown.

It seems that the subject of hold person can't attempt new saving throws because they can't take actions. Is this correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The action to break free of the spell is an exception to the general "cannot take any actions" as it is built into the spell.

Another way to look at it is that the spell prevents any actions except for the special full round action to break free.

Comment: Including the reasoning (that you have then spent your Full Round Action for the turn) might help explain *why* there's a exception.

Comment: @Ifusaso I dont think thats the case here as you can decide to not try to free youself and still have no access to any actions.

Comment: Right... but if it didn't include an action cost, then you'd have your actions after the re-attempt

Answer (score 2):

It directly states in the text, "Each round on its turn, the subject may attempt a new saving throw to end the effect." Though they cannot perform actions, a new save is allowed EVERY turn to end the effect.